# The Stanford CoreNLP returns more than basic relation triples

Tags: stanford-nlp

CoreNLP is returning more triples than we’d expect to get i.e. whole sentences or phrases instead of one or two triples that constitute the essential or basic information conveyed by the sentence.

For example, in the sentence:

> "The preliminary diagnosis was notified to Dr. Tom by Roy Coy MD at
>   16:00 CDT on 11/11/2011."

We expect this triple:

```
preliminary diagnosis; be notify to; Dr. Tom
```

But we get triples like these:

```
1.0 diagnosis be notify by Roy Coy MD at 16:00 cdt on 11/11/2011
1.0 diagnosis be notify to Dr. Tom at 16:00 cdt on 11/11/2011
1.0 preliminary diagnosis be notify to Dr. Tom
```

which in addition to the basic information contain additional details. In an extreme case CoreNLP returns the whole original sentence.

What arguments could we change in order to reduce the CoreNLP output to basic triples? We have experimented with the maximum number of entailments and the triple strict set but they don’t work. We could provide a file with full list of triples.

Java code:

```
java -mx1g -cp stanford-openie.jar;stanford-openie-models.jar;slf4j-api.jar edu.stanford.nlp.naturalli.OpenIE -openie.max_entailments_per_clause= 1 -openie.triple.strict= true -openie.splitter.disable=true
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is, actually, by design. It's not always clear a priori what the level of granularity people would like from OpenIE systems is, and so our system tries to produce all the levels of granularity it can. The intended use here is to produce triples that can be looked up in a database. So, if someone asks a very specific query, the longer triples are returned. If someone asks a simple query, we return the simple triples (and it doesn't matter that there are some longer ones in there alongside them).

Comment: Thank you very much, but are there arguments for OpenIE to extract the basic tuples for automatic use?